# Select column to be inserted based on input column value

Tags: postgresql, pivot

Assume the following two tables (and ignore the quality of the database design):

- Table 1 has columns `id`, `sequence_number`, `value`: it contains many rows.
- Table 2 has columns `id`, `seq1`, `seq2`, `seq3`, `seq4`, `seq5`: it is empty.

The goal is to fill Table 2 with Table 1's value, such that if in Table 1 one row is `sequence_number = 3`; `value = 1564.1`, then in Table 2 one should insert a row with `seq3 = 1564.1`. (the other columns aside from `id` should be empty).

How to do that in SQL? I don't want to hard code all 5 options (because in my actual use case there are over 50.), but I don't know how to condition the column name that should receive the value based on the value.

Comment: I adapted the title to speak of "insert" instead of "update", since that seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a problem of cross tabulation / crosstab / pivot.

Given these exact table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  id int
, sequence_number int
, value numeric
);

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
  id int
, seq1 numeric
, seq2 numeric
, seq3 numeric
, seq4 numeric
, seq5 numeric
);
```

All you need is this basic crosstab query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2
SELECT * FROM  crosstab (
  'TABLE tbl1'
, 'SELECT generate_series(1,5)'
) t(id int, seq1 numeric, seq2 numeric, seq3 numeric, seq4 numeric, seq5 numeric);
```

Also the fastest way I can think of.
You need the additional module tablefunc installed. Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

If either of your tables has more columns, be more explicit in the first parameter and / or adapt to more columns:

```
SELECT * FROM  crosstab (
  'SELECT id, sequence_number, value FROM tbl1'  -- optionally ORDER BY
, 'SELECT generate_series(1,7)'
) t(id int, seq1 numeric, seq2 numeric, seq3 numeric, seq4 numeric
          , seq5 numeric, seq6 numeric, seq7 numeric);
```

#### More automation

If you have to do this often you can automate further:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514334/939860)

Using the 2-parameter form of `crosstab_n()` ***as defined in the linked answer***, the query can be as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab_n('TABLE tbl1', 'SELECT generate_series(1,5)', NULL::tbl2);
```

Replace 5 with 50 if you have that many `seq`*`N`* columns.

Answer (score 2):

By using CASE statements..

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, seq5)
SELECT
  <SOME ID VALUE>,
  CASE WHEN sequence_number = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN sequence_number = 2 THEN value ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN sequence_number = 3 THEN value ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN sequence_number = 4 THEN value ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN sequence_number = 5 THEN value ELSE NULL END
FROM table1
```

If you consider that hard coding, then (as far as I'm aware) your only other option would be dynamic SQL within a plpgsql block.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  row table1%ROWTYPE;
  colName VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
  FOR row in SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LOOP
    colName := 'seq' || row.sequence_number;
    EXECUTE '<SQL HERE THAT USES colName FOR INSERT>';
  END LOOP
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```